# All python files not working

Tags: python

A week ago all my py files were working just fine, but now everything has gone haywire. All python files/games don't work, with most errors being "Traceback error" and that same code used to work just fine before. Here's an example of code that doesn't work:

```
print("Hello")
input()
print(Goodbye)
input()
```

It says hello, then when I press enter, it just says "traceback error". Most problems are associated with the enter key (with inputs). Also tkinter doesn't work. I use: `from tkinter import *` and it says `import error`. I tried again with a capital T, and that magically worked for some reason, though, but that shouldn't be the case. Right now I'm using python 3.3.5, and I had python 2.7.6 previously installed, but I deleted all of that. Please help!

Comment: Without tracebacks we can only guess, but all evidence points towards you using Python 2 to run your code.

Comment: Most of all, questions about general computing hardware and software installation problems are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: it just says "traceback error": I don't think so. It as well gives a traceback with meaningful content.

Comment: "I tried again with a capital T, and that magically worked for some reason, though, but that shouldn't be the case." Why not?

Comment: Python 2 has [`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html), Python 3 has [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). Note the change from `T` to `t`.

Comment: I think you removed the wrong python. In python 3, its "tkinter" and "input", in python 2 its "Tkinter" and "raw_input". If 'T' fixes your tkinter import, you are using 2.x

Comment: @MartinBetz I am missing which semicolons?

Comment: He means quotation marks, I think.

Comment: @glglgl Sorry, it was meant to be for the OP; of course I meant quotation marks. Will delete my comment for not confusing anyone...

Comment: How do you get what else it says after "traceback error"? Sry I'm nooby

Comment: Please create a new script containing only this line: `print(__import__('sys').version)`. Run it and let us know the output.

Comment: 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] -thats what it said on the shell

Comment: @user3516628 And you have invoked this test script in exactly the same way as the scripts which are failing?

Answer (score 2):

In the above example you forgot to put `'Goodbye'` in quotes, but this is not the wider issue. There were significant (including many syntactic) changes between Python 2 and 3, such as using `print` (it is now a function rather than a statement) and the name of the `Tkinter/tkinter` library.

You need to port all of your code to make it work, or better still just leave your old Python  installed and then run such programs in that interpreter.

If you are insistent on moving on to another version, then you should convert all of your scripts using the built-in [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) tool. For future Python 3 programs, see [what is new in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).

**EDIT:**

To convert Python 3 code to Python 2, see the [`3to2`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/3to2) tool. It is not built-in, but it should make your life easier.

Comment: I really don't think the OP needs to learn about how to now fix their Python 3 code to run on Python 2 instead. They need help unscrewing their system instead, which is why I am sending them to *Super User* instead. There is not enough info in this post to diagnose the problem anyway, and we *do not know how damaged the Python 2 setup is* either.